# flask app doesn't use scrapy custom settings

Tags: python, flask, scrapy

I have a perfectly functioning spider. I am integrating it into a flask web app. The spider runs when I want it to, but it doesn't use the settings provided in the settings.py file when ran from the flask app. Hence, I get a 403 response. Note that when I run the spider from the cmd, it uses the settings just fine. How can I get the flask app to run the spider WITH the correct settings?

My spider code:

```
class PostsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

page_number = 0
name = 'posts'
allowed_domains = ['ra.co']


# global artist
# artist = input('Artist name:')
start_urls = [
    f'https://ra.co/dj/ouladomar/past-events?'
]
              }


def parse(self, response):


    if len(response.css('li.Column-sc-18hsrnn-0.inVJeD')) == 0:
        raise CloseSpider('No more events')

    for link in response.css('li.Column-sc-18hsrnn-0.inVJeD div h3 a::attr(href)'):
        yield response.follow(link.get(), callback=self.parse_act)

    next_page = f'https://ra.co/dj/ouladomar/past-events?page={str(PostsSpider.page_number)}'


    PostsSpider.page_number += 1
    print(PostsSpider.page_number)
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)


def parse_act(self, response):
    date = response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/header/div/div[2]//div/ul/li[2]/div/div[2]/a/span/text()').get()
    event = response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/header/div//div/div/div[2]/h1/span/text()').get()
    promotors = response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/header/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[3]/div/div[2]/a/span/text()').getall()
    location = response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/header/div//div[1]/div/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/div/a/span/text()').get()
    country = response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/header/div//div[1]/div/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[1]/div/a').attrib['href']
    venue = response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/header/div/div[2]//div/ul/li[1]/div//span/text()')[1].get()
    acts = response.xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/section[1]/div/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/span/a/span/text()').getall()

    date = re.sub(r'^.*?, ', '', date)

    promotors = ', '.join(promotors)

    if len(date) == 4:
        date = f'99-99-{date}'

    elif len(date) >= 15:
        date = date[5:]

    elif date[-4: -2] == '20':
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d, %Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    else:
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%d %b').strftime('%d-%m') + '-2023'

    country = country.split('/')[-2].upper()

    acts = ', '.join(acts)

    item = {
        'date': date,
        'Event': event,
        'promotors': promotors,
        'Location': location,
        'Country': country,
        'Venue': venue,
        'Acts': acts
    }

    yield item

if __name__== '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(PostsSpider)
    process.start()
```

my flask app:

```
import subprocess

import crochet
crochet.setup()

from flask import Flask , render_template, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher
import time
    
from ScrapyProject.scraperra.scraperra.spiders.artistspider import PostsSpider

# Creating Flask App Variable

app = Flask(__name__)

output_data = []
crawl_runner = CrawlerRunner()


# By Deafult Flask will come into this when we run the file
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")  # Returns index.html file in templates folder.


# After clicking the Submit Button FLASK will come into this
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        return redirect(url_for('scrape'))  # Passing to the Scrape function


@app.route("/scrape")
def scrape():

    process = subprocess.Popen('python ScrapyProject/scraperra/scraperra/spiders/artistspider.py', shell=True)
    process.wait()

    return jsonify(output_data)  # Returns the scraped data after being running for 20 seconds.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: you can use custom settings or set the settings enviornemnt variable.

Comment: @Alexaner I had found both solutions (not tested them yet), but they seem rather workarounds than proper solutions. At least, I assume the web app should take on the settings set in the settings.py file normally right.

Comment: only when you are inside of a proper scrapy project directory.